# duplicity backup fails: "Private key file is encrypted"

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, scp, duplicity

I am trying to upload my first duplicity backup to a remote server and it fails. It is the first time I am using the tool and it did not work before.

```
duplicity /home/me/Documents/ scp://me@<ip-address>//home/me/bak
```

This is the answer I get:

```
BackendException: ssh connection to me@<ip-address>:22 failed: Private key file is encrypted
DEBUG:duplicity:BackendException: ssh connection to me@<ip-address>:22 failed: Private key file is encrypted
```

Logging in via `ssh` works fine.

I have searched the web but could not find any possible solution. My only hunch is that it could be related to my `.ssh` directory: which contains multiple identities and thus multiple `.pub` and key files

EDIT: with `-v 9` I get the following output (a lot more, but just showing last part):

```
ssh: Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:sshbackend:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
ssh: HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:sshbackend:HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
ssh: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:sshbackend:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
ssh: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:sshbackend:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
ssh: Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:sshbackend:Compression agreed: none
ssh: kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:sshbackend:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
ssh: Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:sshbackend:Switch to new keys ...
Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-O8U6r5-tempdir
Level 5:duplicity:Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-O8U6r5-tempdir
Backend error detail: Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1581, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1567, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1406, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1140, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1015, in set_backend
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 223, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 209, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/ssh_paramiko_backend.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.config['port'], e))
 BackendException: ssh connection to me@<ip-address>:22 failed: Private key file is encrypted
```

doesn't tell me much more though

Comment: pure scp works too

Comment: Do you have a password on your SSH key?

Comment: yes, my SSH key has a password. Maybe I should try with one without?

Comment: I just tried with a key without password and I get the same....:(

Answer (score 2):

seems like the paramiko backend does not support providing a passphrase for your secret key currently.

try `pexpect+scp://` or better `pexpect+sftp://` if possible

alternatively specify a secret key you want to use via

```
--ssh-options="-oIdentityFile='/my/backup/id'"
```

and make sure it is *not* passphrase protected.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: `Attempt 1 failed. ImportError: No module named pexpect`

Comment: Apparently `pexpect` is a package and should be installed, but as `rsync` worked for me, I did not try. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked is using `rsync` as backend.

Which is finally surprising, I have no idea why the `scp` backend did not work, as pure `scp` works too.

Won't accept my own answer because it is not really the solution to the problem, just a workaround. But at least I can use it now.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with a passphrase key. Setting the key to the following two environment variables solved it for me: `FTP_PASSWORD` and `PASSPHRASE`

https://duplicity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duplicity.backends.ssh_paramiko_backend.html